# Setting up a secure Network

Tags: networking, internet

I have a home network that I want to make more secure so I brought a second router with the aim of setting up a second, separate network at home to put the more important device on. I checked out the options of LAN - LAN and WAN - LAN connection and decided to go for the WAN - LAN since that made the 2 networks independent from each other. However the issue is that I cannot get internet on the second network?

I setup the system with the ethernet cable going from the WAN port of the second router to the LAN port of the main router. I changed the IP addressing for both networks to be different but I still couldn’t get internet connection. I even disabled the DHCP server from the main router to see if this helped but it did not.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Connect your main router to your modem, then connect your computer to the router via Ethernet. Configure it as you normally would to set up the network. Since this router will be handling the connection to the internet, set it up as if you were only using a single router.

If you are creating a LAN-to-WAN network, set the primary router's DHCP service to give out addresses between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.50.

Then change the IP address of your second router so that it matches the first router, except increase the second-to-last digit by one (e.g. 192.168.1.1 becomes 192.168.2.1). Ensure that the subnet mask is the same as the primary router.

If you are making a LAN-to-WAN network, change the secondary router's WAN IP address to 192.168.1.51.

The DHCP server on the secondary router should hand out addresses between 192.168.2.2 and 192.168.2.50.

Also be sure to disable UPnP on your second router.

Comment: I tired this but it didn't work. The strange thing is when I restarted the main router to try and force it to find the devices, it took the IP address of the 2nd router and showed its interface when I connected to it? Any idea why it would do that?